# How can I make React wait for a Redux action before render?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im trying to make my own Blog App but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Here are my codes for my "startSetMyBlogs":

```
export const startSetMyBlogs = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const myBlogs = [];
        const blogRef = database.ref('blogs/')
        const uid = getState().auth.uid;

       //join table to get blogs match with logging in user

        return database.ref(`author-blog`)
            .once('value', snap => snap.val())
            .then(childSnapshot => {
                childSnapshot.forEach((blog) => {
                    if (blog.val() == uid) {
                        blogRef.child(blog.key).once('value').then(blogSnapshot => {
                            myBlogs.push({
                                id: blogSnapshot.key,
                                ...blogSnapshot.val()
                            })
                        })
                    }
                })
       // Dispatch another action to set redux state.
              dispatch(setUserBlogs(myBlogs));
         })
    }
}
```

my "setUserBlogs" action:

```
export const setUserBlogs = (myBlogs) => ({
    type: 'SET_USER_BLOGS',
    myBlogs
})
```

So how can I wait for "setUserBlogs" action to finish before passing props to my BlogList component ?

Answer (score 0):

Use it as below: Dispatch an action once you get the as you want it from Firebase.

```
        return database.ref(`author-blog`)
            .once('value', snap => snap.val())
            .then(childSnapshot => {
                childSnapshot.forEach((blog) => {
                    if (blog.val() == uid) {
                        blogRef.child(blog.key).once('value').then(blogSnapshot => {
                            myBlogs.push({
                                id: blogSnapshot.key,
                                ...blogSnapshot.val()
                            })
                        })
                    }
                })
              dispatch(setUserBlogs(myBlogs));
         })
```

NOTE: API call is async so you have to wait for the data to assign it to state.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hmmmm, I was going to push all my blogs first then add all of them. If I do this way, I have to call an action every blog ? Does this affect my performance ?

Comment: so once you add your all data, then you can push it. but it should be work as I said.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to store and pass on a loading state until your data is ready

```
export const startSetMyBlogs = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const myBlogs = [];
        const blogRef = database.ref('blogs/')
        const uid = getState().auth.uid;

       //join table to get blogs match with logging in user
        dispatch({type: 'SET_LOADING', payload: true});
        return database.ref(`author-blog`)
            .once('value', snap => snap.val())
            .then(childSnapshot => {
                childSnapshot.forEach((blog) => {
                    if (blog.val() == uid) {
                        blogRef.child(blog.key).once('value').then(blogSnapshot => {
                            myBlogs.push({
                                id: blogSnapshot.key,
                                ...blogSnapshot.val()
                            })
                        })
                    }
                })
              // Dispatch another action to set redux state.
              dispatch(setUserBlogs(myBlogs));
              dispatch({type: 'SET_LOADING', payload: false});
         })
    }
}
```

Once you do that you can use this loading state in the component to render a loader

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
   blogs: state.blogs,
   isLoading: state.isLoading
}
```